# const WCHAR * myVar vs const char * myVar

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I've developed a small bmp to jpg conveter.
Following code is working and providing exact results as I need

```
BOOLEAN convertBMPtoJPG(const WCHAR *src_bmp_path,const WCHAR *dest_jpeg_path);
```

then calling function as,

```
const WCHAR *src_bmp_path = L"test.bmp";
const WCHAR *dest_jpeg_path= L"test.jpg";
convertBMPtoJPG(src_bmp_path,dest_jpeg_path);
```

However I need the function to be changed as following (as per requirements I've been given), but doing so results as a compilation error.

```
BOOLEAN convertBMPtoJPG(char *src_bmp_path,char *dest_jpeg_path);
```

then function would be called as, (though I need to follow just the prototype as above),

```
char *src_bmp_path = "test.bmp";
char *dest_jpeg_path= "test.jpg";
convertBMPtoJPG(src_bmp_path,dest_jpeg_path);
```

Another question on stackover provided too much information about Win32 types, however I yet couldn't resolve the issue.
I'm not that great in Win32 API, please guide me what's going wrong in later approach.

**Edit:**

Error Message:
**error C2664: 'Gdiplus::Status Gdiplus::Image::Save(const WCHAR *,const CLSID *,const Gdiplus::EncoderParameters *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'const WCHAR *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast**

Comment: seeing as how you've decided to let us guess what the compilation error is, perhaps you're missing `const`?

Comment: What format is your char * string?  Is it UTF-8?  Is it in the user's default codepage?  Could it be a different codepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image::Save()` only accepts `WCHAR*` values, so your `char*` wrapper will have to convert to `WCHAR*`, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()` (just like Win32 API Ansi functions do when they call Win32 API Unicode functions internally), eg:

```
std::wstring towstring(const char *src)
{
    std::wstring output;
    int src_len = strlen(src);
    if (src_len > 0)
    {
        int out_len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, src, src_len, NULL, 0);
        if (out_len > 0)
        {
            output.resize(out_len);
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, src, src_len, &output[0], out_len);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

BOOLEAN convertBMPtoJPG(char *src_bmp_path,char *dest_jpeg_path)
{
    return convertBMPtoJPG(towstring(src_bmp_path).c_str(), towstring(dest_jpeg_path).c_str());
}

BOOLEAN convertBMPtoJPG(const WCHAR *src_bmp_path, const WCHAR *dest_jpeg_path)
{
   // your existing conversion logic here...
}
```

Comment: There's a big assumption baked into `CP_ACP`.  You really need to know what encoding the strings you're being handed are in, and what's expected if the desired path cannot be represented in that encoding.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I've got it and fixed. The call to 'stat = image->Save(dest_jpeg_path, &encoderClsid, NULL);' assumes accepting only WCHAR*, but I thought I was not passing string to the function properly.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: agreed, which is why modern code should not be Ansi-fyed anymore. It is best to write code that targets Unicode only. But the requirement was to expose an Ansi version of `convertBMPtoJPG()`, so one workaround would be to have that function take an extra codepage parameter as input and pass it to `towstring()` so it can pass it to `MultiByteToWideChar()`. At least that puts the responsibility on the caller to know the encoding of the source `char*` values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: We don't actually know what the requirement was, other than that it use `char*`.  That might mean UTF-8 or any one of several other encodings other than the system's default ANSI codepage.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: all the more reason to have the caller pass in the actual encoding of the `char*` values to the `char` version of `convertBMPtoJPG()` so it can convert them to Unicode correctly when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like your are compiling for Unicode support.  The list of Win32 data types can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

WCHAR is defined as -

```
 A 16-bit Unicode character. For more information, see Character Sets Used By Fonts.
 This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
 typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
```

Here is a link showing how to convert between various string types [String Conversion Samples.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)